# How do I calculate the private key in RSA?

Tags: rsa

Given $n=pq$ for $p,q$ known, I can calculate $\phi(n)$.

$e$ is selected such that $\gcd (e,\phi(n)) = 1$.

Using this, how do I calculate the RSA private key?

---

Example:

> I have $n = 35$, with $(p,q)=(5,7)$.
>   I have also computed $\phi(n)=24$, and selected $e$ such that $\gcd (e,\phi(n)) = 1$ by taking $e=23$.
>
> Calculate the private key.

Comment: Take a look at the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: I figured it out and I'll answer my question soon

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its scope is too local. It's unlikely that anyone else will need to calculate a key with these exact parameters. Maybe if you edited the question to make it more general...

Comment: I recommend you reading  Conrado's post in [here](http://alicebob.cryptoland.net/understanding-the-extended-euclidian-algorithm/), it's easier to understand than that on the Wiki

Answer (score 2):

The private key $d$ of RSA algorithm with public parameters $(N,e)$ is such that:

$ed \equiv 1\mod{\phi(N)}$. Since by definition $e$ and $\phi(N)$ are coprime then with extended euclidean algorithm you can find such $d$: $ed +k\phi(N)=1$

Consider that to compute $\phi(N)$ you should know how to factor $N$ since $\phi(N)=\phi(p)\phi(q)=(p-1)(q-1)$

To see why this is correct imagine an encryption of the message $m$ to be $c=m^e\mod{N}$.
Then to decrypt you compute $c^d=m^{ed}\mod{N}=m \mod{N}$

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the decent way of solving for $d$ (the private key).

I have $n=35$, with $(p,q)=(5,7)$. I have also computed $\phi(n)=24$, and selected $e$ such that $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$ by taking $e=23$. To calculate the private key, we need to use the formula:

$$d = e^{-1} \mod \phi(n)$$

This gives us $d = 23$, which happens to be the same as $e$, a coincidence.

Comment: These are standard techniques you can find in all books.We say the same thing.In order to compute the inverse you can use the extended euclidean algorithm

Comment: Also, this isn't a much of a coincidence, because $e=23=-1\pmod{24}$ and so $e^2=(-1)^2=1\pmod {24}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it is you're pointing out?  If e=23 then $e^2$=$23^2$ and 529 mod 24 = 1 but why is it not a coincidence that _d_ and _e_ are both 23?  In my very limited travels in cryptography, I usually don't see _d_ and _e_ being the same value.  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be realizing.

Comment: The world of algebra knows no luck or coincidence.