# RSA: Private key calculated from public key?

Tags: rsa

The wiki article on RSA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) says that **d** is "the modular multiplicative inverse of e (mod φ(n))" , where **d** is the private key and **e** and **n** make up the public key. How come an interceptor cannot calculate the **d** in the exact same manor as the encrypter does, if the interceptor has knowledge of **e** and **n**?

Comment: The encrypter doesn't know $d$. Encryption only needs $e$ and $n$.

Comment: When finishing writing an answer, I recalled writing something quite similar in the past. Maybe this could be considered a duplicate of [Why are these techniques not feasible to crack RSA?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12152/4082).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When p and q are primes and ​ n = p$\cdot$q , ​ one will have

{p,q} ​ ​ ​ = ​ ​ ​ $\bigg\{\hspace{-0.06 in}n\hspace{-0.04 in}+\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.05 in}-\hspace{-0.03 in}\phi(n)\pm \sqrt{\left(n\hspace{-0.04 in}+\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.05 in}-\hspace{-0.03 in}\phi(n)\right)^{\hspace{.04 in}2}-(4\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}n)}\hspace{-0.05 in}\bigg\}$ ​ ​ ,

so for [semiprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime), computing $\phi$ is equivalent to factoring.

The above reasoning doesn't work for [multi-prime RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11287/991), but even there, there's no obvious way for the adversary to compute $\phi$ of the modulus more easily than just factoring the modulus.

Comment: Actually, it's known that computing $\phi$ is computationally equivalent to factoring, even for multiprime RSA modulii.  For that matter, the knowledge of any nontrivial pair $e, d$ which work as an RSA public/private keys is equivalent to factoring (where $e=d=1$ and $e=d=-1$ are the trivial pairs)

Answer (score 2):

What you know from the public key:

- $e$
- $n$

What you need to calculate $d$:

- $e$
- $\phi(n)$ ([Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)) *or* $\lambda(n)$ ([Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function))

The functions $\phi$ and $\lambda$ are [multiplicative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), which is essential in the following way: The calculation is straight forward, if you know the factorization of $n$. In general the way to calculate the functions for composite values is to factorize them first.

In the original paper *A Method for Obtaining Digital
Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems* by Rivest, Shamir and Adleman (1978), they already noted a probabilistic algorithm to calculate $\phi(n)$ if you know $e \cdot d$ (which can be quite a lot larger), which is basically Miller's algorithm described in *Riemann's hypothesis and tests for primality*, Miller (1975). In 2004, May published *Computing the RSA Secret Key is Deterministic Polynomial Time Equivalent to Factoring*, which is a deterministic algorithm for that problem, showing that factoring and calculating $d$ from $e$ and $n$ is equivalent in polynomial time.