# Generate private key from public key RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa

I am doing a tutorial where my lecturer (PhD) gave me an optional question to do relating to RSA.

He said: write a python function that takes as input the server’s public key and then uses that to compute the server’s private key. Print out the server’s private key to standard out.

Because according to him, 16-bit or 17-bit keys can be easily factorized on your computers.

How am I able to do this. I have searched all over and people have said RSA private keys cannot be generated by public keys.

I am asking for guidance, please.

Comment: **Hint:** Wolfram alpha can factor that very easily or the `factor` command in Unix.

Comment: Yes, but I am seeking to construct the Python `function`

Comment: Did you hear [sieve](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/)

Comment: Just use the Sagemath

Comment: For RSA keys _of the size actually used_ factoring is practically impossible -- the best known algorithms would use more energy than exists, and take longer than the universe's lifetime. For 16 bits it is trivial, and in fact up to about 800 bits is currently practical, which is why 1024-bit keys, which were formerly common, have been deprecated or prohibited since about 2014 and most people today use 2048-bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take the server’s public key.

Parse the modulus and public exponent.

(A public key contains the public exponent and modulus)

Factor the modulus into `p` and `q` elements.

Calculate the private key as normal.

***i.e.***

1) *calculate* $$Carmichaels$$ $$totient:$$ $$\phi= lcm (p-1)(q-1)  $$

2) calculate `d` the private key as $$d*e\equiv   1mod \phi$$

3) celebrate

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this.

Comment: I was able to do the calculation as you said but my results came out looking like this even though the factors were indeed correct. What should I make of it?  `2.6785953446012912e-05`

Comment: @JermaineHall modular integers don't use ordinary ('real', or on a computer floating-point) arithmetic. Given the factors, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20923/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29055/